# vuex unknown action type in NuxtJS

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

In my store I have:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  searchedBrands: null,
  searchedCars: null,
  displaySearchResults: false,
  hovering: false,
  arrowIndex: -1,
})

export const getters = {
  displaySearchResults(state) {
    return state.displaySearchResults
  },
}

export const mutations = {
  setSearchResults(state, data) {
    state.searchedBrands = data.results[0].hits
    state.searchedCars = data.results[1].hits
  },
  displaySearchResults(state) {
    state.displaySearchResults = true
  },
}

export const actions = {
  setSearchResults({ commit }, data) {
    commit('setSearchResults', data)
  },
  displaySearchResults({ commit }) {
    commit('displaySearchResults')
  },
}
```

and I am trying to call an action in one my page component methods with:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('displaySearchResults')
```

but it doesn't work and I get the following message:

> [vuex] unknown action type: displaySearchResults

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Even tho, it may be fine I'm not sure that having a getter + mutation + action called in the same way is a good thing overall. Rename your getter to `getSearchResults`, your mutation to `DISPLAY_SEARCH_RESULTS` and keep your action. Then try again. Otherwise, maybe share us a [repro] or a github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the right namespace solved the issue and the Vuex action could work then.